# During running of application in docker: gethostbyname error - how to solved?

Tags: docker, unix

Try to start some applicationX in the docker container. For my task, I should handle this in `su` mode.
Action `$ ./appplicationX` does output `gethostbyname error`.

When I try `$ strace ./applicationX` I get:

```
[user@169ce41e4a2f applicationX]$ strace ./app3
execve("./applicationX", ["./applicationX"], 0x7fff92a94580 /* 12 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1a2a000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4aeaa000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13035, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 13035, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`&\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2156272, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3985920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4a8bc000
mprotect(0x7f6d4aa80000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d4ac7f000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c3000) = 0x7f6d4ac7f000
mmap(0x7f6d4ac85000, 16896, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4ac85000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea5000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea3000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f6d4aea3740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d4ac7f000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d4aeab000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f6d4aea6000, 13035)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1a2a000
brk(0x1a4b000)                          = 0x1a4b000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1a4b000
stat("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=224, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea9000
read(3, "multi on\n", 4096)             = 9
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f6d4aea9000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea9000
read(3, "# Generated by NetworkManager\nse"..., 4096) = 224
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f6d4aea9000, 4096)            = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1949, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea9000
read(3, "#\n# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# An ex"..., 4096) = 1949
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f6d4aea9000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13035, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 13035, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=61560, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2173048, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4a6a9000
mprotect(0x7f6d4a6b5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d4a8b4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xb000) = 0x7f6d4a8b4000
mmap(0x7f6d4a8b6000, 22648, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4a8b6000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d4a8b4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f6d4aea6000, 13035)           = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=174, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea9000
read(3, "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost\n::1\tlocalhos"..., 4096) = 174
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f6d4aea9000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13035, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 13035, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=31344, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2121984, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4a4a2000
mprotect(0x7f6d4a4a8000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d4a6a7000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7f6d4a6a7000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\2009\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=109976, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2202112, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4a288000
mprotect(0x7f6d4a29e000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d4a49e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f6d4a49e000
mmap(0x7f6d4a4a0000, 6656, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4a4a0000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d4a49e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d4a6a7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f6d4aea6000, 13035)           = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("195.xxx.xxx.x")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "\26#\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\6blabla\22secure-progr"..., 46, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 46
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [106])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "\26#\201\203\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\6blabla\22secure-progr"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("195.xxx.xxx.x")}, [28->16]) = 106
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("195.xxx.xxx.x")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "\252\354\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\6blabla\22secure-progr"..., 51, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 51
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [51])                = 0
recvfrom(3, "\252\354\201\203\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\6blabla\22secure-progr"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("195.xxx.xxx.x")}, [28->16]) = 51
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("195.xxx.xxx.x")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "\342\214\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\6blabla\22secure-progr"..., 57, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 57
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [120])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "\342\214\201\203\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\6blabla\22secure-progr"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("195.xxx.xxx.x")}, [28->16]) = 120
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13035, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 13035, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libnss_myhostname.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\36\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=86464, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2181296, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4a073000
mprotect(0x7f6d4a085000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d4a284000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x11000) = 0x7f6d4a284000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\26\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=20048, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2114112, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d49e6e000
mprotect(0x7f6d49e72000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d4a071000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f6d4a071000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0PS\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1136944, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3150136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d49b6c000
mprotect(0x7f6d49c6d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d49e6c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x100000) = 0x7f6d49e6c000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=43712, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128952, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d49964000
mprotect(0x7f6d4996b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d49b6a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f6d49b6a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdw.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\237\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=338672, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2427184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d49713000
mprotect(0x7f6d49761000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d49961000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4e000) = 0x7f6d49961000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19248, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d4950f000
mprotect(0x7f6d49511000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d49711000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f6d49711000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320*\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=88720, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2184192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d492f9000
mprotect(0x7f6d4930e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d4950d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x7f6d4950d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200m\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=142144, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2208904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d490dd000
mprotect(0x7f6d490f4000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d492f3000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f6d492f3000
mmap(0x7f6d492f5000, 13448, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d492f5000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\23\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19896, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d48ed8000
mprotect(0x7f6d48edc000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d490db000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f6d490db000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/elfutils/tls/x86_64/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/elfutils/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffdd2e9b820) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/elfutils/tls/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/elfutils/tls", 0x7ffdd2e9b820) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/elfutils/x86_64/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/elfutils/x86_64", 0x7ffdd2e9b820) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/elfutils/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/elfutils", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/lib64/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=99944, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2191824, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d48cc0000
mprotect(0x7f6d48cd7000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d48ed6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f6d48ed6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/elfutils/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=90248, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2183272, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d48aaa000
mprotect(0x7f6d48abf000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d48cbe000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x7f6d48cbe000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/elfutils/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\2000\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=157424, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2249352, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d48884000
mprotect(0x7f6d488a9000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d48aa8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7f6d48aa8000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/elfutils/libbz2.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libbz2.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\27\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=68192, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2162024, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6d48674000
mprotect(0x7f6d48683000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6d48882000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe000) = 0x7f6d48882000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d48882000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d492f3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d48aa8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d48cbe000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d48ed6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d490db000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d4950d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d49711000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d49961000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d49b6a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d49e6c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d4a071000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6d4a284000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f6d4aea3a10)         = 43
set_robust_list(0x7f6d4aea3a20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f6d490e3860, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f6d490ec630}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f6d490e38f0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f6d490ec630}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7f6d4aea6000, 13035)           = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="169ce41e4a2f", ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d4aea9000
write(1, "gethostbyname error\n", 20gethostbyname error
)   = 20
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to run `strace` with `-f`, there's no call to `gethostbyname()` in this trace.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But maybe I explain not so good.
The problem comes when I run the program `./applicationX`. The
`strace` output I send that you can see details of issue.
As I can imagine the `applicationX` try to find socket `/var/run/nscd/socket`, but with `su` I can't even `mkdir`, and more of them I can't find information in this case what socket means.